# Issue with flash video size in html

Tags: html, flash, object, video, overflow

I am trying to put a 1024x168 flash video(swf) in a web page and but the video is getting clipped, I wish to have scroll bar appear whenever it overflows. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head>
test
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow: auto;">
<object id="M97012085" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  width="100%"  height="100%"  style="overflow: auto; align:middle;" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0">
  <param name="movie" value="path_to_swf" />
  <param name="loop" value="false" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="play" value="false" />

<embed bgcolor="#ffffff" align="middle" name="M97012085 loop="false"  src="path_to_swf"  width="100%"  height="100%" style="overflow: auto; align:middle;"  play="false"  wmode="transparent" quality="high"  allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please advice how can I have the scrollbars appear when video overflows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by setting the height and width to 100% on your object you are telling it to fill up the whole div, which is why you don't get scrollbars.

Try setting the actual dimensions for the height and width and then when a video's dimensions are larger then the div you should see the scrollbars.

Comment: I tried putting the actual size but it doesn't shows scroll bars either.

Comment: Yeah that was the case really, I was specifying wrong video size, thanks heaps for your help.